# Why iterations over the same tf.data.Dataset give different data each iteration?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to understand how **tf.data.Dataset** works.

It says on the documentation that [take](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#take) returns a dataset with a certain amount of elements from that dataset. You can then iterate over a single sample (in this case a batch):

```py
import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

# Construct a tf.data.Dataset
ds = tfds.load('mnist', split='train', shuffle_files=True)

# Build your input pipeline
ds = ds.shuffle(1024).batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

single_batch_dataset = ds.take(1)

for example in single_batch_dataset:
  image, label = example["image"], example["label"]
  print(label)
# ...
```

Outputs:

```
tf.Tensor([2 0 6 6 8 8 6 0 3 4 8 7 5 2 5 7 8 7 1 1 1 8 6 4 0 4 3 2 4 2 1 9], shape=(32,), dtype=int64)
```

However, iterating over it again, gives different labels: (continuation of last code)

```py
for example in single_batch_dataset:
  image, label = example["image"], example["label"]
  print(label)

for example in single_batch_dataset:
  image, label = example["image"], example["label"]
  print(label)
```

Outputs:

```
tf.Tensor([7 3 5 6 3 1 7 9 6 1 9 3 9 8 6 7 7 1 9 7 5 2 0 7 8 1 7 8 7 0 5 0], shape=(32,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([1 3 6 1 8 8 0 4 1 3 2 9 5 3 8 7 4 2 1 8 1 0 8 5 4 5 6 7 3 4 4 1], shape=(32,), dtype=int64)
```

Shouldn't the labels be the same, given that the dataset is the same?

Comment: Of course not, you're shuffling the data... _edit_: twice

Comment: @NicolasGervais - perhaps one could imagine a scenario where the shuffling is defined once and is used for every iteration.

Comment: @jakub ah yes it makes sense from that perspective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the data files are shuffled and the dataset is shuffled with [`dataset.shuffle()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?hl=ru#shuffle).

With `dataset.shuffle()`, the data will be shuffled in a different way on each iteration by default.

One can remove `shuffle_files=True` and set the argument `reshuffle_each_iteration=False` to prevent reshuffling on different iterations.

The `.take()` function does not imply determinism. It will just take N items from the dataset in whichever order the dataset gives them.

```py
# Construct a tf.data.Dataset
ds = tfds.load('mnist', split='train', shuffle_files=False)

# Build your input pipeline
ds = ds.shuffle(1024, reshuffle_each_iteration=False).batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

single_batch_dataset = ds.take(1)

for example in single_batch_dataset:
    image, label = example["image"], example["label"]
    print(label)
    
for example in single_batch_dataset:
    image, label = example["image"], example["label"]
    print(label)
```

Output:

```py
tf.Tensor([4 6 8 5 1 4 5 8 1 4 6 6 8 6 6 9 4 2 3 0 5 9 2 1 3 1 8 6 4 4 7 1], shape=(32,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([4 6 8 5 1 4 5 8 1 4 6 6 8 6 6 9 4 2 3 0 5 9 2 1 3 1 8 6 4 4 7 1], shape=(32,), dtype=int64)
```